# SSMS add comma separates thousands in the rows counter result

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In SSMS - Is it possible to add a "comma separates thousands" in the rows counter result ?

Sometimes I get very large numbers that it is difficult to immediately distinguish which number it is...[image]

Comment: It shows a comma in [my window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAKlc.png). Perhaps it uses your Windows regional settings?

Comment: @DavidG - I looked at my Windows settings and it seems that number design is with a comma.

Comment: And the digit grouping setting? See my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That number is displayed according to how your operating system number format is set. For example, if I set my `Digit grouping` to `123456789` it will show like this:

[image: No grouping]

However, if I set it to `123,456,789`, the output looks like this:

[image: With grouping]

Note that the settings window looks like this:

[image: Format settings window]

Note, you need to restart SSMS if you change your settings.

Comment: Very strange, I have exactly the same settings as yours but it is shown without a comma in the SSMS. What's even moe strange is that in the area of "example" in your image displayed without a comma and in mine with, as I said, the rest of the settings looks the same.